# Display Wait cursor in MFC application when the Java is launched from the application, uptill it finishes its process

Tags: c++, mfc

I am developing an app where I am launching an Java application from within my MFC application. I want to display the wait cursor from the time process is carried out by the java application until it ends.
Here's the code I have Implemented.

```
    void CDropboxSync::OnBnClickedDbxPcToCloud()
{
    STARTUPINFOW        siStartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
    SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
    if (CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe"), TEXT(" -jar DbxUpldDwnld.jar u"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA)&siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Please install Java Runtime Environment(JRE) on your PC\n Link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html"), MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

I want to start the wait cursor as soon as the processing of java application starts and want to end the Wait cursor when the application process is done. How can this be done. I have tried to implement BeginWaitCursor and EndWaitCursor. But could get the desired output.Please point me to rite direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the above code it seems your code does the following,

1. Set WAIT Cursor
2. Create the java process
3. Then closes process and thread handles

It is never setting normal cursor back. So your application would be displaying Hour glass even after finishing the java process.

This is what I have got in my mind,

1. Set Wait Cursor in OnBnClickedDbxPcToCloud()
2. Start a new  thread which does the following

   2.1) Create the java process

   2.2) Wait for the java process to finish by calling WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess)

   2.3) Then notify UI thread by sending a custom message to the Window.
3. In the custom window message handler you set back the normal
   (arrow) cursor.